# Angularjs: Angularjs ngCookie.js is giving some error

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

i tried to inject angular-cookies.js in my HTML file but seems it has some type error or to make it accurate an "error" in the js file. The error showing in my log is "TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function"
and the js is from there website("https://angularjs.org/"). is anyone have solution for this? thank you

Comment: unfortunately, you need to present the *entire* error message, along with the possible lines of code where the error might occur in order to receive adequate troubleshooting advice.  there is indeed no `.info` function on the `angular.module` object, so the error is accurate, but it's not obvious at all what you are trying to do that created this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same issue and i solved it by deleting the line from the angular-cookies.js file that gives you the error, display the js file in the browser console to identify the line and just delete it. I hope it helps.

Comment: you're welcome i hope this helps more than one person because it took me like 3 or 4 weeks to use ngCookies.

Comment: agreed on you on that, don't know why people down voted my post which is this is really an existing bug in angularjs ngCookies..